# How to make every side of an object light the same?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

In this case, I would like them to be the same light red as the left side without ambient light

[image: This is the picture]

Comment: You want the object to be not lighted or lighted the same? Not affected by light or with a personal light? You need to be more clear

Comment: @LeoverloadI I don't know I want it to be affected by it, but the side witch is pointed towards the light should be the same as the opposite side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an object with the same colour in all faces without having the light to change in the scene you can use an **unlit material**

1. create a new material
2. select an unlit shader (for example default/unlit)
3. apply that material to your object
4. apply a texture with a flat colour that you want (for example a simple PNG of the red colour)

Now you have an object all with the same colour in all faces and it is not affected by light.